# Calculating a point between two points on a slant line with a distance $d$

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I have points $(x_1, y_1)$ and $(x_2, y_2)$ on a line. I need to calculate the point $(x_3, y_3)$ which is some distance $d$ away from $(x_1, y_1)$ . I had calculated the slope using the formula,
$$
m = \frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}
$$
where $m$ is the slope

[image]

Then I used the slope to calculate the angle $\theta = \arctan(m)$. With the angle and start and end points I used the following formula to calculate the coordinates of the point $(x_3, y_3)$ 
$$
\begin{split}
x_3 &= x_2 + d\sin \theta\\
y_3 &= y_2 + d\cos \theta
\end{split}
$$
I tried to plot the point I obtained. However, the angle of the new line always seems wrong and I am not sure where I am making the mistake, slope or the angle formula?  This is the line generated after the calculations, the $(x_3, y_3)$  seems to be with completely wrong angles.

[image]

Comment: makes sense to me

Comment: I think one possible cause of mistake is that the range of $\arctan$ function is $(-\pi/2, \pi/2)$. However your $\theta$ should assume values in the range $[0, 2 \pi)$ to account for different orientations. One way is to manually correct the value obtained in by $\arctan$ to the correct quadrant. For example, if $m = -1$, $\arctan(-1) = \pi/4$. However, your $\theta$ can also be $3\pi/4$ so you should also try with that value and see if it fits on your line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given $p_1,p_2$ and computed $D = \|p_1-p_2\|=\sqrt{(x_2-x_1)^2+(y_2-y_1)^2}$ you can construct $p_3$ as follows

$$
p_3 = p_1 + \frac{d}{D}(p_2-p_1)
$$

or

$$
\cases{
x_3 = x_1+\frac{d}{D}(x_2-x_1)\\
y_3 = y_1+\frac{d}{D}(y_2-y_1)\\
}
$$